# Storage Space Linux

Tags: storage

I am curious if you could help me determine the actual amount of space used:

```
[xxx ~]$ ll
total 50
drwxr-xr-x  5 xxx  5 Aug 30  2015 canopy/
drwxr-xr-x  3 xxx 3 Feb 12  2014 Enthought/
drwxr-xr-x  3 xxx 25 Sep  3 03:49 metr150/
drwxr-xr-x  2 xxx 11 Sep  2 18:29 metr163/
drwx------ 17 xxx 17 Dec  6  2014 metr51/
drwxr-xr-x  2 xxx 19 Sep  2 18:14 public_html/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root      14 Aug 26 21:00 sandbox -> /sandbox/xxx
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Try using `du` instead of `ll`, as the output of `ll` doesn't show anything related to file size.

Comment: Install ncdu: `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ncdu`. Change into the directory you want to check the space of and then run `ncdu`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `du -H` and [man du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) for more about the command.

```
NAME   du - estimate file space usage

DESCRIPTION  Summarize disk usage of the set of FILEs, 
recursively for directories.


 -h, --human-readable
          print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

Example:

```
~/Desktop$ du -H
4696968 ./Jessica.Jones.Season.1
2907180 ./Re Zero kara Hajimeru Isekai Seikatsu
109132620   .
```

The last line is a total of all files.